# Making PyPy work with any version of Python (>2.5)?

Tags: python, pypy

I want to use PyPy with Python 2.6. The default version (PyPy 1.4.1) seems to be 2.5 when downloading binaries. Google doesn't seem to be helping much, advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [download a nightly build](http://buildbot.pypy.org/nightly/trunk/) if one exists for your platform. They support Python 2.7 and an official release with this support is supposed to happen in the next days, as PyPy developers are sprinting at PyCon right now.

Edit: As of 2012, [PyPy stable releases](http://pypy.org/download.html) support Python 2.7 and there is ongoing effort to support 3.x.

If you use an OS for which no nightlies are available, you can still [build PyPy from source](http://pypy.org/download.html#translate) using latest code from Mercurial. You'll need a somewhat beefy machine for that and building on Windows (specially 64 bits) has a couple of hurdles to clear, so you might want to join #pypy in freenode if that is what you need.